# Select/filter data in excel based on two column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I just want to ask how I can show or filter data in excel so I can get the result like when we use in SQL syntax :

```
SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE column1 = "a" OR column2 ="b"
```

I already try using filter but the filter only works for one column

Comment: Use this [link](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b). with thanks to @xificurC, I update the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @shA.t, Advanced Filter is an option. By putting the criteria (e.g. `="a"` in A2) then the filtering is based on either criterion:

[image: SO23884273 example]

However provided a helper column is available I prefer a formula such as:

```
=OR(A1="a",B1="b")
```

and then filtering that column to select for TRUE.